# How to add mysql config in Laravel Sail docker-compose.yml?

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker-compose

I have a fresh Laravel 8 installation together with mysql:8.0 image.

I want to add some configurations to MySql.

This is my mysql service in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
```

This works fine. If I now try to add a `my.cnf` to the volumes like this:

```
volumes:
    - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    - './docker/8.0/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf'
```

and reboot the container with `sail down` and `sail up`, then it suddenly fails with:

```
mysql_1         | 2021-11-06T13:26:52.465786Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
mysql_1         | 2021-11-06T13:26:52.465813Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

How can I include the configs?

Comment: When you change the mysql service in the docker-compose.yml do you do docker-compose down and up for the changes to take effect? If so, was the mysql service running after that? Did you try to check if the supplied value, a directory /var/lib/mysql-files exists and is accessible by mysql? Anything in the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom `my.cnf` is overwriting settings (pid-file, socke and datadir) which causes the mysql service to fail. To not overwrite them, one needs to keep the original `my.cnf` file which is:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL
```

So in your case you had to add:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
```

Comment: Where is the default `my.cnf` located?

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon your question since i had the same problem.
I am using Laravel with Sail with the current mysql docker container.

I inspected the docker container and the mysql configuration is saved like so:

The base `my.cnf` file is located here:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

*(there is also a folder `/etc/my.cnf.d/`, but putting a custom .cnf file there did not work, since it is not included inside `/etc/my.cnf`)*

What i did in my `docker-compose.yml` file **after i copied the original contents** of `/etc/my.cnf` from the docker container is:

```
volumes:
    - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    - './docker/8.2/my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf'
```

I needed it since i got `MySQL: Error Code: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126).` that may be fixed like that:

```
innodb_strict_mode = OFF
```

You can inspect the mysql docker configuration by loggin into the running container like that (see https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql):

```
$ docker exec -it nameOfMysqlContainer bash
```

To list the files in the etc folder when logged in:

```
$ ls -la /etc/
```

Comment: Strange, according to docs the configuration should be added to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf ` https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql